Pip 24 on Python 3.11.9 can't resolve a non-specific and specific dependency version
I am getting this dependency resolution error in pip 24 (from pip 23) about a dependency in one of my projects:
The conflict is caused by:
      The user requested packageA
      The user requested (constraint) packageA==1.0.0+f2ca1bb6c7e907d06dafe4687e579fce76b37e4e93b7605022da52e6ccc26fd2

The requirements.txt of one of my packages has listed packageA without a version meaning "any version will do" and as a constraint I list the current dev version of each package.
In previous versions of pip this worked as expected: the resolution is to prioritize the specific version of the package over the non-specific version of the package; instead of an error pip installs packageA==1.0.0+f2ca1bb6c7e907d06dafe4687e579fce76b37e4e93b7605022da52e6ccc26fd2 since that satisfies the requirement packageA (any version). However after upgrading pip it is unable to resolve that scenario. Is there a new flag I'm missing or has there been a fundamental change to pip I'm unaware of?
To clarify, no packages in either requirements or constraints specify anything other than the package name and the package version (in the case of the contraints). There is no python_version or anything extra like that.
